# Should Linq Concat work if the first collection is empty?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working in LinqPad right now. I have the below 2 lines of code:

```
roleAssnd.Concat(roleAssnd2);
roleAssnd.Dump();
```

If I look at both items (`roleAssnd` and `roleAssnd2`) before the Concat, `roleAssnd` has 0 records, and `roleAssnd2` has 3. However, after the Concat, `roleAssnd` has 0 still.

I would think it would have 3.

Is this just a LinqPad issue? If this is how it should work, how can I handle the possibility that the first collection is empty?

Comment: You have to assign the result of `Concat` to something it does not change the collection you call it on.

Comment: If `roleAssnd` is a `List<T>` you could do `roleAssnd.AddRange(roleAssnd2);` to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `Concat` works with empty collections, the only thing is to assign the result back *(to a new or existing list)*.

`Concat` doesn't modify the collection in place.

[`Enumerable.Concat<TSource>` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx)

> The immediate r**eturn value is an object** that stores all the
>   information that is required to perform the action. The query
>   represented by this method is not executed until the **object is
>   enumerated**

If you want to assign the result back to `roleAssnd` then use:

```
roleAssnd = roleAssnd.Concat(roleAssnd2).ToList();
```

**Or, you can also use `AddRange`** since it is a `List<T>` like:

```
roleAssnd.AddRange(roleAssnd2);
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is a collection of extension methods on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. These don't actually mutate the collection, but rather return a new enumerable that will yield the results of the operation.

You could write either `roleAssnd.Concat(roleAssnd2).Dump();` or

```
var result = roleAssnd.Concat(roleAssnd2);
result.Dump();
```

EDIT:
One way to look at it is to compare it to the following

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
x + y; // note, this won't even compile
x.Dump();
```

`+` doesn't actually modify `x`, it returns a new result that you have to examine.